# site stats は表示されなくなったのでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, 完了

トップページ(ja.stackoverflow.com)の右側にあった site stats が、ちょっと前(2015/11月中旬ぐらいでしょうか、気づいたらなくなってたのでおぼろげですが、、)までは表示されていたように思いますが、今日見るとそれがなくなっていました。

これは、表示されないことになったのでしょうか?

Comment: 現在開発者と確認中です。現在米国の感謝祭（Thanksgiving）休暇のため、来週になるかもしれませんが、フォローしています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12月18日の追記：

統計が表示されています。

---

別の統計を集まる実験を行っているため、Site Statsは表示することができません。

後日実験が終わってから再びSite Statsを戻す予定です。

Comment: これはしばらく先になるのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 今日から表示されています